# How to increment number of items in datagridview with button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to add new food to the datagridview when the food button clicked.
Food tabs generated from the FoodGroup table in database.
I want to increment the count when the button is clicked for second or third time...

```
public void loadFoods()
    {
        var q = context.FoodGroups.ToList();
        foreach (var f in q)
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            var foods = context.Foods.Where(fd => fd.GroupID == f.GroupID).ToList();
            foreach (var food in foods)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Width = 100;
                btn.Text = food.FoodName.ToString();
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.addFood);
                panel.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
            TabPage tab = new TabPage();
            tab.Text = f.GroupName.ToString();
            panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tab.Controls.Add(panel);
            tcMain.TabPages.Add(tab);
        }
    }
```

I added a method to button click but it adds new row for every new click:

```
private void addFood(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button) sender;
        var fo = context.Foods.Where(ff => ff.FoodName == b.Text).FirstOrDefault();
        dgvFoodList.Rows.Add(fo.FoodID, fo.FoodName);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's adding a new row because you're telling it to. Every time you click a button, `dgvFoodList.Rows.Add()` is getting called, which adds a new row to the table. If you want to increment the `Count` column, you need to check the table to see if the food has already been added. If it has, update the count column. If not, add a new row. This will only add a new row if the food does not exist already.

Comment: Create a model for the `FoodOrder`, including `Food` and `Count`. Then by click on the button, check if the food exists in the `BindingList<FoodOrder>`, then increase the count, otherwise add a new `FoodOrder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is you are adding the food by every click on buttons, while you should check if the food exists in the ordered foods, then increase the count.

To do so, as an option you can create a model for the `FoodOrder`, including `Food` and `Count`. Then by click on the button, check if the food exists in the `BindingList<FoodOrder>`, then increase the count, otherwise add a new `FoodOrder`.

**Example**

This example has been written independent from db:

```
public class Food
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class FoodOrder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

```
List<Food> foodList; //List of all foods
BindingList<FoodOrder> foodOrders; //List of orders which is shown in data grid veiw

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load foods, here I created a dummy list of foods
    foodList = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => new Food { Name = $"Food {x}" }).ToList();

    //Initialize food orders
    foodOrders = new BindingList<FoodOrder>();

    //Add button for each food
    foodList.ForEach(f =>
    {
        var b = new Button() { Text = f.Name };
        b.Click += (s, ea) =>
        {
            var order = foodOrders.Where(o => o.Name == f.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            //If food already ordered, increase the count, otherwise add to orders
            if (order != null)
                order.Count++;
            else
                foodOrders.Add(new FoodOrder { Name = f.Name, Count = 1 });
            //Refresh data grid veiw
            foodOrders.ResetBindings();
        };
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
    });
    //Show orders in data grid view
    dataGridView1.DataSource = foodOrders;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Aghaei. I did it with your code and some minor changes. Now i have another question: If i have another field called "FoodPrice", how can i multiply the count and foodprice and show it in another column in datagrid?

Comment: You're welcome. It's just an example showing how you can use a model for the orders.

Comment: You can add properties to `FoodOrder` class, it's a model for a each line of `DataGridView`. One property `int FoodPrice {get;set;}` and initialize it with the price of the food, at the same time which you add an instance of `FoodOrder` to the `foodOrders` . Also another property `int TotalPrice {get { return FoodPrice * Count;}}`. It shows the total price for that row.

Comment: In a real world application, instead of repeating all properties of the `Food` in `FoodOrder`, it's better to have a`Food` property in `FoodOrder` class. This way you have access to all properties of the `Food` in `FoodOrder`, including its price. Also if you are using EF, this `FoodOrder` can be one of your entities.